# $\forall y, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ $((x+y)^2 +5(x+y) +6 > 0)$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, real-numbers

I came up with a proof that $\forall y, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ $((x+y)^2 +5(x+y) +6 > 0)$ but also the negation, where is the error?

Pf: Fix $y \in \mathbb{R}$, choose $x = 2-y$ then $(x+y)^2 +5(x+y) +6 =(2-y+y)^2+5(2-y+y)+6=4+10+6=20 \gt 0 $ $\square$

The negation is $\forall x, \exists y \in \mathbb{R}$ $((x+y)^2 +5(x+y) +6 \leq 0)$

Pf: Fix $x \in \mathbb{R}$, choose $y=-2-x$ then $(x+y)^2 +5(x+y) +6 =(x-x-2)^2+5(x-x-2)+6=4-10+6=0 \leq 0 $ $\square$

The error is that the negation is $\exists y, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ $((x+y)^2 +5(x+y) +6 \leq 0)$ thank you to everyone for your help!

Comment: The statement is true, since you can always pick an $x$ to resolve the inequality.

Comment: Your proof is essentially correct (except for the unfortunate "$> 0$" before the first $=$ sign.

Comment: But the negation is true $\forall x, \exists y \in \mathbb{R}$ $((x+y)^2+5(x+y) \leq 0)$ choosing $y=-2-x$ so that the expression becomes $0 \leq 0$.

Comment: @EzTheBoss2: That's not the correct negation of the statement. The negation of a statement of the form $\forall y:\exists x:P(x)$ is actually $\exists y:\forall x:\neg P(x)$.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's help, the solution guide put that as the answer and I was going a little crazy.

Comment: I also think the statement is true. For intuition, suppose $y=0$. Then we get a parabola of the form $x^2+5x+6$ which is actually less than zero from $-3 < x < -2$ by an amount of $y=0.25$. But we can make it greater than zero by choosing the right $x$.

Comment: @joe what is the negation of P(x) in this context?

Comment: Once $y$ is fixed, you have a monic quadratic in $x$. A polynomial with a positive leading coefficient always takes on positive values.

Comment: @EzTheBoss2: Sorry, I should written $P(x,y)$ in my comment, not $P(x)$. The negation of $P(x,y)$ in this case is simply $(x+y)^2 +5(x+y) +6 \le 0$

Comment: I see the mistake in the negation thank you!

Comment: Okay I now typed up my understanding of the proof of the negation of the statement in the original question and I still can't spot the mistake.

Comment: You can swap $\forall x \forall y$ to be $\forall y \forall x$.  You can swap $\exists x \exists y$ to be $\exists y \exists x$.  You *cannot* swap $\exists y \forall x$ to be $\forall x \exists y$.  Thinking you can gives absurdities like "Everyone has some friend" being equivalent to "There is some person who is everyone's friend".

Comment: Thank you, that clears everything up!

Answer (score 1):

In such situation, we can approach it graphically and algebraically.

The first one is given below:

[image]

The second one is detailed below:

\begin{align*}
(x + y)^{2} + 5(x + y) + 6 > 0 & \Longleftrightarrow [(x + y)^{2} + 2(x + y)] + [3(x + y) + 6] > 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x + y)(x + y + 2) + 3(x + y + 2) > 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x + y + 3)(x + y + 2) > 0
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that it suffices to consider that $x + y > -2$ or $x + y < -3$.

Hopefully this helps!